# Prettier error messages for Rails nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

Take my order checkout process for example,

Order belongs to guest

guest belongs to user

user has many phone numbers

number is an attribute on phone number.

I'll get error messages like this:

`[:"guest.user.phone_numbers.number", "is an invalid number"]`

How do I go about returning a prettier message?
Something like, 'Invalid phone number format.' or 'Phone number is invalid'

I realize I could hack it out of the string, but I'm hoping for a Rails Way of defining the association names or something? with I18n support?

Comment: You can add your custom message in `config/locales/en.yml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the event you need to access nested attributes within a given
>   model, you should nest these under model/attribute at the model level
>   of your translation file:
>
> ```
> en:   
>   activerecord:
>     attributes:
>      user/gender:
>        female: "Female"
>        male: "Male"
> ```
>
> Then `User.human_attribute_name("gender.female")` will return "Female".
>   - [Rails Guides - Translations for Active Record Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      guest/user/phone_numbers:
        number: 'Phone number'
```